# Error : "html/template:test_template: \"'\" in attribute name: \"Emoji';'><br /></span></p>\\n</div\"" occurred while executing template

Tags: html, go

I am using  "html/template" package, while try to execute the template by using `t.Execute(wr io.Writer, data interface{}) function error return : Error : "html/template:test_template: \"'\" in attribute name: \"Emoji';'><br /></span></p>\\n</div\"".`

template content is given below:

```
<p style="font-family: Lato, sans-serif, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, 'Noto Sans', 'Apple Color Emoji', 'Segoe UI Emoji', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Noto Color Emoji';">test</p>
```

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/vqNv3YCQWml -- There's no error in the html example given in the question. The error message that you cite does not match the html.

Comment: Can you share the source code?

Comment: please check the issue on https://go.dev/play/p/qM49YITYZ_c

Comment: @AnoopKumar that's not valid html. How do you expect an html parser, Go or in any other language, to understand `style='font-family: Lato... 'Segoe UI', ...'`? You can't use `'` within `' ... '` without proper escaping. If you want to use `'` then you have to enclose the `style` value in `" ... "` instead of `' ... '`.

Comment: @AnoopKumar basically you have two options, use single quotes inside double quotes `style=" ... 'foo'"`, or use double quotes inside single quotes `style=' ... "foo"'`. https://go.dev/play/p/fMlnpFWZ9j-